# Javascript function not working, any ideas?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, arguments

Basically I have this:

```
<svg width="100px" height="100px">
    <line x1="3" y1="1" x2="3" y2="100" onclick="play("e1")" />
</svg>
<audio id="e1">
    <source src="qwerty.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<script>
function play(b){
    document.getElementById(b).play();
}
</script>
```

Any ideas of what went wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: please specify: what do you want to achieve, what happened exactly, and all the things you think matter with the topic. Also, write a better title. Include images, snippets or fiddles are always helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of quotes! They were not escaped. Either you can swap with `'` and `"` or escape it with a backslash like `onclick="play(\"el\")"`

Change your element declaration to

```
<svg width="100px" height="100px">
    <line x1="3" y1="1" x2="3" y2="100" onclick="play('e1')" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't get such a simple thing! Feeling so dumb right now. Anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it should work now

```
 <svg width="100px" height="100px">
        <line x1="3" y1="1" x2="3" y2="100" onclick="play('e1')" />
    </svg>
    <audio id="e1">
        <source src="qwerty.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    <script>
    function play(b){
        document.getElementById(b).play();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you welcome, would u please validate the answer if it's solve the pb